# re-initialize css @keyframes on text change

Tags: jquery, css

I'm utilizing keyframes to fade text into an element, but it only happens the very first time text is loaded into that element, (when the element is first populated).  What changes would I need to make so that whenever text is entered into the element it retriggers the keyframe?

```
<div id="foo"></div>

.test {  
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #a59eb5;  
  animation: fadein 5s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

/* the first time I populate text into this element, it fades in over 5 seconds.  
Changing the text does not re-trigger this fade. */

$('#foo').html('asdfasdfasdf');
```

Is there any way to do this using CSS?  I realize I could re-do this in such a way that I `.addClass` and `.removeClass` with jQuery each time to trigger a fade-in/fade-out, but I was hoping there was a more efficient way of doing this through CSS.

codepen:  http://codepen.io/lordterrin/pen/GmrPoQ

Comment: You have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the question makes sense.  CSS is about separation of style from content, and now you're asking it to be content-aware to the point of responding to DOM mutation events?  Just set/remove classes.

(Then you would use a transition instead of an animation, which also makes sense because you just want the fade to happen once - AIUI - per text change.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery function for that: [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/). Remember, it has to be hidden before you can fade it out.

```js
$('#foo').hide(); //Has to be hidden before it can bed faded in.

var visible = false;

$("button").click(function() {
  $("#foo").fadeToggle(5000);
  if ( visible === false) {
    $('button').text("Fade Out");
    visible = true;
  } else {
    $('button').text("Fade In");
    visible = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Fade in</button>
<div id="foo">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Ok - that's fine - I'll go with the jQuery solution.  Thanks!